# How to check if a member chosen from the getUser option has a specific role in discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am making a command with my bot that first checks if a targeted player has a specific role. the problem is that it fails to figure out if the person has the role or not, it always defaults to not having it.

```
            // Points remove command
            if (interaction.commandName === 'points-remove') {
                const player = interaction.options.getUser('target');
                const playerid = player.roles.cache.has('1136220928666251325');
                const pToRemove = interaction.options.getInteger('points');
                const sqlQ = `UPDATE playerdata SET points = points - ${mysql.escape(pToRemove)} WHERE playerid = ${mysql.escape(player.id)}`;
                if (playerid) {
                    con.query(sqlQ, (error, result) => {
                        if (error) throw error;
                        interaction.reply({ content: `${player} has lost ${pToRemove} succesfully!`, ephemeral: true });
                    });
                } else {
                    interaction.reply('Cannot remove from unregistered player!');
                }
            }
```

Basically, if the person doesn't have the 'registered' role, the command won't do anything. However it always goes to the else statement.
(I apologize for the formatting of the code, it copy pasted terribly)

Comment: Hi, 
it enters the else case if you have no `playerid`. The `playerId` is taken from the `player.roles.cache`. I assume, because you are using a cache, that the cache is filled async, but you are reading from it synchron. Maybe you are accessing the cache before it is filled. 
Can your provide the code, where and when you fill the `player.roles.cache`. 

Its often a better to use an async cache implementation like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64441185/5247706).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**User**'s don't have roles! You're code is absolutely right, except for the following line:

```js
// ❌
const player = interaction.options.getUser('target');
```

Changing the above code to the following should fix your issue!

```js
const player = interaction.options.getMember('target');
```

Comment: Thank you so much that one problem was stumping me and I couldn't find a single thread talking about the getUser option!!